# Salesforce Duplicate Management - Duplicate rules order of execution

Tags: duplicate-management

If we have more then 1 rule on 1 object and we will update the all the fields on which we have matching rules created then How do we determine the order rules fire, or whether we can get them all to fire at once?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. 
 Item number 9 in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.duplicate_rules_create.htm&type=5&language=en_US) is pretty clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the order of duplicate rules on one object. Check this image:-

[image]

You can reorder them as per your requirement. You can also look at this:- [Execution order of multiple Duplicates rules on an Object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296977/execution-order-of-multiple-duplicates-rules-on-an-object)

Comment: Thanks @Sanket Kumar

Comment: @NikhilKumar if it resolved your issue, you can accept it as an answer.